# Did Azoth/Kylar die early in The Way of Shadows?

Tags: night-angel-trilogy

I read the [Night Angel trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night_Angel_Trilogy) by [Brent Weeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent_Weeks) a while ago, and I'm currently re-reading the first book, [*The Way of Shadows*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Way_of_Shadows).

> After Brant Agon threatens Azoth in order to get to Durzo Blint, Blint appears to stab and kill Azoth to make a point that he can't be threatened.
>  This being my second read-through, I'm noticing implications that Azoth/Kylar might actually have been killed by Durzo (he recalls hazy dreams of a yellow-eyed wolf, and Momma K points out that it's easy to misjudge poison with a child.
>  This is also after the kakari has, if not yet bonded, at least 'marked its territory' on the boy (when he's trying to defend Doll Girl from Durzo).

So my question is twofold.

1. Did Azoth actually die, and thus was brought back to life?
2. If so, who died so that he could live?

Comment: We don't use a `spoiler` tag; if you think part of your question should be obscured, [there's spoiler markup](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1). Ideally your title shouldn't be a spoiler, because it's there for everyone to see; the body matters less.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like you can't have multiple spoiler paragraphs right in a row, or else the site barfs. That's annoying.

Comment: Spoiler markup is a bit fiddly; it's the system's way of telling you not to use too much of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azoth didn't die at that point.

I don't have the first or second book to hand, but:

> He hadn't fully bonded to the Kakari yet. That doesn't happen until the night he tries to steal what he thinks is the silver kakari, so he isn't immortal yet.

Additionally,

> He isn't given the choice between death and immortality until after Roth kills him near the end of the book.

I can't look up the quote, but in the second book:

> He is killed by Scarred Wrable and the Wolf lambasts him for dying so many times already, he mentions the number of times he's died, which I believe he mentions is three. (Roth, Tenser and now Scarred Wrable).

I do have the third book to hand, however and in it:

> In chapter 57, Kylar finally realises what immortality costs him and the wolf explains what each death has cost: "Serah Drake died when Roth killed you. Mags Drake died for Scarred Wrable's arrow on the trail. Ulana Drake died when the Godking killed you." ... "'And for my blasphemy? When I took money to be killed?' 'Jarl.'".  He doesn't mention the death of any character for a separate death.